# elasticsearch define a new data type when set mappings

Tags: elasticsearch

```
        client.admin().indices().prepareCreate("test_index")   
        .addMapping("test_type", "{\n" +                
                "    \"test_type\": {\n" +
                "      \"properties\": {\n" +
                "        \"test_filed\": {\n" +
                "          \"type\": \"abc\"\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  }")
        .get();
```

I want to customize a data type when setting up mappings， such as abc,so i can Store it into es,
How do I modify the source code?

Comment: There are no custom data types for fields in elasticsearch. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#_field_datatypes

Comment: i imean change es'source code to customize a data type in mappings,i just want to know how to modify the source code,where es check the data type？

Comment: Why do you need this? I think that there is another way to solve your problem. Because changing the source code of a complex search engine is a bad idea.

Comment: another way？ which way？